# Dividing column values with value in the column based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

How I divide column values with one of the values in the column based on a value in other column. So if I have value 2015 in the column A then all the values in column B should be divided with the value in the row with 2015 in A.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : (2014, 2015, 2016), "B" : (100, 200, 300)})
???
result = pd.DataFrame({"A" : (2014, 2015, 2016), "B" : (0.5, 1, 1.5)})
```

Comment: `df['B']/df['B'][df['A'] == 2015].values[0]` ?

Comment: @Epsi95 I think he mentioned 2015 as an example. Rather, he wants a generic solution.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['B'] =  df['B']/df['A']
```

It works exacly how you need I think.